# Jest tries to report coverage on untested JSON files and throws error

Tags: javascript, jestjs, code-coverage

Link to demo on replit.com showing the error: https://replit.com/@chipit24/jest-playground.

When run, the test passes but I see the following unexpected error in the output:

```
Running coverage on untested files... Failed to collect coverage from foo.json
ERROR: foo.json: Missing semicolon
```

Here is my `jest.config.json`:

```
module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/**'],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['package.json', 'package-lock.json', 'node_modules', 'coverage'],
  transform: {
    '.+\\.json': '<rootDir>/jsonTransform.js',
  },
};
```

The [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array) for `collectCoverageFrom` mention (emphasis mine):

> If a file matches the specified glob pattern, coverage information will be collected for it **even if no tests exist for this file and it's never required in the test suite**.

That's fine. I have JSON files laying around that end up in the "collect coverage from" set of files, however, since I set up a transform for JSON files, I was expecting the JSON files to be transformed to valid JS files. Here is my `jsonTransform.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  process(src) {
    return src;
  },
};
```

But it seems that when collecting coverage data, Jest will treat my JSON files as JS files regardless of the transform. Is this a bug or is there a better solution other than adding all affected JSON files to `coveragePathIgnorePatterns`?